# Attaching an on click event to a table header

Tags: javascript, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MSIE and addEventListener Problem in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695376/msie-and-addeventlistener-problem-in-javascript)
>   [Returning the Name of a column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016125/returning-the-name-of-a-column-header)

For the life of me, and to the extent of my knowledge with javascript, I can't seem to get this go, its failing at line 13. Im basically trying to attempt to add an onclick event to a TH to alert me of its value. Im using IE7.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



function init() {

var titles = document.getElementsByTagName("th"); 

for ( var i = 0, len < titles.length; i < len; i++ ) {    
    titles[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
        alert( this.innerHTML ); 
    }, false); 
} 

}//end of function

</script>

</head>

<body onload="init()">

<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
    <tr>
        <th>FRUITS</th>
        <th>COLORS</th>
        <th>VEGGIES</th>
        <th>NUMBERS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>apples</td>
        <td>red</td>
        <td>carrots</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>oranges</td>
        <td>blue</td>
        <td>celery</td>
        <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pears</td>
        <td>green</td>
        <td>brocoli</td>
        <td>789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mangos</td>
        <td>yellow</td>
        <td>lettuce</td>
        <td>098</td>
    </tr>
</table>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `addEventListener` is not supported in IE7.

Comment: Please don't double post the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your `for` statement, you were incorrectly assigning to `len` variable, so replace your following line:

```
for ( var i = 0, len < titles.length; i < len; i++ ) {
```

for this one:

```
for ( var i = 0, len = titles.length; i < len; i++ ) {
```